# Blocking connection to internet only when certain program is run

Tags: windows-8.1, firewall, steam

I wonder if that is possible. For example:

I want to block "Steam"s  connection to the internet when I run a certain game.

Is that possible or do I have to keep disabling and enabling the rule?

Comment: You could write a couple of batch scripts that you keep on your desktop that enable/disable the firewall rules. You could add the "start steam..." command to your "firewall block" script so that it blocks and then runs Steam.... ?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Could you tell me how?


@FastEthernet Why do you need to know? I just need an answer not another question :)
Like I said, I need to disable Steam internet connection so I can play a game

Comment: @KaitoKid I'm just trying to figure out what issue you are having that requires you to block Steam from accessing the Internet in order to play a game, because that shouldn't be necessary under normal circumstances.

Comment: Like I said, I wonder if that is possible, I would like to know how to do that. No issues :)